# Pausing a loop when the queue is 'full'

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm doing a web crawler with the [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.11.0/docs/api.md)!.

The loop passes to the function (loadPage (URL)) a valid url, but would like to pause the loop when N pages are being handled by crawling.

I thought about doing a timeout, with an average time the puppeer takes to run. But I do not think it's a solution. But, I am open to any discussion.

Thank you.

--- Editing *for future reference* ---

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const stores = require('./data.json').stores;

const MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS = 5;
let TOTAL_PAGES = 0;

const start = async () => {
//@TODO Create a separate log routine
console.log('Total de Lojas', stores.length)

let actualStore = null;
let activatedStores = [];

for (const store of stores) {
    if (store.active) {
        activatedStores.push(store)
    }
}

//@TODO Create a separate log routine
console.log('Lojas ativas', activatedStores.length)

try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false //Debug porpouse
    });
    const pagePool = await Promise.all(Array.from(
        new Array(MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS),
        () => browser.newPage()
    ))

    while (activatedStores.length !== 0) {
        //@TODO Create a separate log routine
        console.log(`Stores left: ${activatedStores.length - MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS}!`)
        await Promise.all(
            activatedStores.splice(0, MAX_CONCURRENT_TASKS)
                .map((store, i) => loadPage(store.siteMap, 
pagePool[i], store))
        )
    }

    await browser.close();

} catch (error) {
    //@TODO create function to generate error logs
    console.error(error)
}
}


/**
 *Function to load pages
 *
 * @param {string} url - a valid url
 * @param {puppeter} page - puppeteer browser.newPage()
 * @param {Object} store - the settings of this store
 */
const loadPage = async (url, page, store) => {
const opts = {
    timeout: 0,
    waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'
}
page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36')

await page.goto(url, opts);

//@TODO Create a separate log routine
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => document.location.href));
}

start()
```

Comment: why do you want to pause the loop? Do you want it to loop, pause while loading page, then loop again, pause while loading page, loop again etc...

Comment: @NickParsons Thnks.
I need to pause to have more control of the requests.
Firstly because I can not wait for the crawler to make one request at a time.
Second, some sites here in Brazil block access when they receive many requests. And creating a routine with some IP pooling is not going to be possible for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code, it's hard to be sure what exactly you need. Maybe this example can give you some hints.

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const urls = Array.from(
      new Array(20),
      (_, i) => `https://example.org/?foo=${i}`
    );
    const numberOfConcurrentTasks = 3;

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const pagePool = await Promise.all(Array.from(
      new Array(numberOfConcurrentTasks),
      () => browser.newPage()
    ));

    while (urls.length !== 0) {
      console.log(`URLs left: ${urls.length}.`);
      await Promise.all(
        urls.splice(0, numberOfConcurrentTasks)
            .map((url, i) => processDoc(url, pagePool[i]))
      );
    }

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();

async function processDoc(url, page) {
  await page.goto(url);
  console.log(await page.evaluate(() => document.location.href));
}
```

Comment: Thnks so much. That solves my question, yes.
By the way, I'm sorry I forgot an example.

Answer (score 2):

I am not able to provide you a code sample here, but definitely, you should look into a [iterators and generators concept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). Generators use principle of non-blocking pause, that allows you to do some computations, stop and do other logic, return to your computations.

Comment: @ShevchnkoViktor Thnks.I'm going to study the interators again.